# php: is_numeric treats leading and trailing spaces differently

Tags: php, types, type-conversion, php-7.3

My php version:

```
➜  ~ php -v
PHP 7.3.1 (cli) (built: Jan 10 2019 13:16:34) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.1, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I dont understand why spaced value in function `is_numeric` behaves like this?

```
➜  ~ php -a

php > var_dump(is_numeric('0012432'));
bool(true)
php > var_dump(is_numeric(' 0012432'));
bool(true)
php > var_dump(is_numeric('0012432 '));
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 2):

This function handles leading spaces differently than is_int(), is_float(), is_real(), is_long(), and is_double().

```
is_numeric(" 12345") = true
is_int(" 12345") = false
is_float(" 12345") = false
is_real(" 12345") = false
is_long(" 12345") = false
is_double(" 12345") = false
```

I found a bug report open for these cases, not sure if they will be working on this,

[Bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67719)

Comment: 5 year old bug report and no comments. Also, you can vote on the bug and maybe they will comment/close/fix etc...

Comment: I found the pull request, but last year the author decided to closed it. He wrote: Having waited 6 months for this 3 year old PR to get moving, I'm quite confident that this is going nowhere, so I'm closing the PR.                            https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/753

Comment: Thanks, @abestard. I writted comment in this bug report.

Answer (score 0):

So does every other part of the core PHP language that accepts numeric strings. It's an annoying inconsistency, but it is intentional and has been like this for many years. I am personally intending to fix this in a future version.

Comment: nice to see this feature moving, is this part of an RFC? Due to performance implications, I think Nikita proposed a PHP internals discussion. Is it going to be part of the following [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/string_to_number_comparison)? I like to keep track of these changes, so I can simplify my code later. thanks!

Comment: @abestrad https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2317, in draft, I intend to work on it more soon